# jQuery autocomplete timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

For some reason the ajax requests I make on the website I'm working on abort half of the time. This is resolved when I set a timeout for the ajax request like shown below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/question/why_wont_it_work",
    timeout : 1000,
    success: function(){ /*do stuff*/ }
});
```

Sadly the timeout fix doesn't seem to work with the jquery autocomplete. I'm using it like this:

```
$( "#questionTags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/question/tags",
    timeout: 1000,
    select: function(event, ui) { /*do stuff*/ },
});
```

I checked the jQueryUI documentation on the website and didn't see the timeout option there either. Now this is pretty annoying since half of the time my request will abort and I won't get the results 
I want. Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your autocomplete source requiring a server trip? How much data are you working with? People generally don't want to wait 20 seconds for an autocomplete to populate so I would suggest making that faster.

Comment: 20 seconds is indeed way too long, put it there to make sure the timeout wouldn't be the problem for the abort.

Comment: I'm new to jQuery and it took me awhile to figure out that for my long-running autocomplete request, if I lost focus on the autocomplete box (say, to check firebug), then the autocomplete results would not display, even if the AJAX request was successful.

Comment: @WattsInABox Took me a long time, too–til I read your comment. Argh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can supply an arbitrary function to the `source` parameter. So you could manually make an AJAX request and specify the `timeout` option:

```
var xhr = null; /* To prevent multiple calls from happening while one is in progress */
$("#questionTags").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        if (!xhr) {
            xhr = $.ajax({
                url: "/question/tags",
                timeout: 20000,
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                     xhr = null;
                     response(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    response([]);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    select: function(event, ui) { /*do stuff*/ },
});
```

But I'm with [@El Ronnoco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009353/jquery-autocomplete-timeout#comment12796140_10009353), you probably want to seriously speed up your request. 20 seconds is a long time to wait.

Answer (score 4):

If `source` is a string, jQuery autocomplete does the code shown below to load the data, so it doesn't set a timeout.

You could set the timeout globally by using [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 20000,
});
```

But that would affect all your ajax requests.

---

**Code from jquery.ui.autocomplete.js :: _initSource**

```
self.xhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: request,
    dataType: "json",
    context: {
        autocompleteRequest: ++requestIndex
    },
    success: function( data, status ) {
        if ( this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex ) {
            response( data );
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        if ( this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex ) {
            response( [] );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$target.autocomplete('/question/why_wont_it_work',{
        delay: 2000
    });
```

Comment: You have to explain something.

Comment: And that fixes the problem because?